# How to assign Woocommerce Product ID in Jquery

Tags: variables, woocommerce

While using Woocommerce Product Addons, I am fitting a datepicker for specific input fields.
The code below works for the product with ID '1381' ,

How to I assign a woocommerce's `$product_id` into the jQuery code here.

```
// Check the name of your addon field in the source. Example: addon-7934-test-addon
jQuery ( "input[name^=addon-1318-install-date-mmddyy]" ).datepicker( {
minDate: 0,
"dateFormat": 'mm-dd-yy'
} );
```

Where only `1318` should be replaced by the current product & should display datepicker if its available.

All input names are in this format `name="addon-PRODUCTID-install-date-mmddyy"`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also need to figure out how to access the product ID's from jquery...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same challenge - rather than try and assign a product ID, I have used a wildcard on the field name - in my case its a delivery date - so you can strip part of the name and just search for the existence of part of the string, So for the example above it would be:

```
// Check the name of your addon field in the source. Example: addon-7934-test-addon
jQuery( "input[name*='install-date-mmddyy']" ).datepicker( {
minDate: 0,
"dateFormat": 'yy-mm-dd'
} );
```

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks for taking time to reply. I'll try it this week & update again. :)